# Hyper-V machine version

Tags: hyper-v

I have a cluster with Hyper-V machines version 5.0 and 8.0. I want to replicate these to another server. This server was a Windows 2012R2, but to receive the 8.0 machine, i did an in-place upgrade to Windows 2016.

I have been fighting with replicating. I received an error "Hyper-V failed to enable replication for virtual machine - The request is not supported" with an errorcode of 0x80070032.

After a lot of investigation, i have found out, that i am missing the 8.0 machine configuration:

```
PS C:\Users\administrator.CBIT> Get-VMHostSupportedVersion

Name                                 Version IsDefault
----                                 ------- ---------
Microsoft Windows 8.1/Server 2012 R2 5.0     True
Prerelease                           254.0   False
Experimental                         255.0   False
```

```
C:\Users\administrator.CBIT>ver

Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.14393]
```

If I create a new machine I get the wizard with the 2. generation question. Some how the Hyper-V manager is the new version. But it will still store an version 5.0 configuration file.

How do i get the Hyper-V running version 8.0?

Thanks
Thomas

Answer (score 0):

The solution was to raise the Cluster Functional Level from 8 to 9. After this version 8.0 was accepted.

'''
Get-Cluster -Name localdemo.demo.local | Update-ClusterFunctionalLevel
'''